# Can't get post variable from json

Tags: php, json, curl, slim

I have a Slim php application that has a route that looks like:

```
$app->post('/products', function () use ($app) {


    $allPostVars = $app->request->post();

    print_r($allPostVars); //Returns a json of the right name attribute


    print_r($app->request->params('name')); //Doesn't return anything

});
```

I'm using Resty CLI to make a curl request to the application that looks like:

```
POST /products '{"name":"Hello World"}'
```

The $allPostVars is working showing a JSON of what I sent, but the `print_r($app->request->params('name'));` is returning NULL.

Why would this be? 
Thanks for all help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Resty CLI - it might be sending the data as a string,and not key-value pairs. Could you try the same using curl: `curl -X POST -d name='Hello World' /products`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may or may-not work but, I have an API that I made myself, when I send JSON with my API I sent it in the body of the request, so its not assigned to a POST var like you would expect. The way I get the data is like this:

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input'); 

print_r($inputJSON);
```

I hope this works for you :)

In fact, nevermind what I said above. Its just dawned on me that you have the data already. Just read it from the $allPostVar and run a JSON decode on it.

```
$allPostVars = $app->request->post();

$array = json_decode($allPostVar, true);

print_r($array);
echo $array['name'];
```

That is the way you will have to access the data because as I said above its not assigned to a var.